# Non expandible Gtk+3 Sidebar in python for a treeview-like interface

Tags: python, gtk

I have a window in python with 2 box containers aligned horizontally, one is meant to be a sidebar and the other should be a text view. The sidebar becomes bigger that the text view, and it gets resized when I resize the window, still overtaking the textview. what can I do to fix this?
[image: The program I'm trying to make. Look at the dominant size of the sidebar at left.]

The code I use to make the text view ("textview") and sidebar ("editview").
***This is part of my code!***

```
def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Translator")

    self.box = Gtk.Box(spacing=0)
    self.add(self.box)

    self.box_editview = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=0, expand=False)
    self.box.pack_start(self.box_editview, True, True, 0)

    vseparator = Gtk.Separator(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
    self.box.pack_start(vseparator, False, False, 0)

    self.box_textview = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=0)
    self.box.pack_start(self.box_textview, True, True, 0)

    self.css_styling()
    self.create_textview()
    self.create_editview()

def create_editview(self):
    self.palette1 = Gtk.Expander()
    self.palette1.set_spacing(6)
    self.palette1.set_label('Main')
    self.palette1.set_size_request(100,400)

    self.box_editview.pack_start(self.palette1, False, False, 0)

    grid = Gtk.Grid()
    label = Gtk.Label("    font  ")
    button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("some very cool font")
    grid.add(label)
    grid.add(button)
    self.palette1.add(grid)

def create_textview(self):
    scrolledwindow1 = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    scrolledwindow1.set_hexpand(True)
    scrolledwindow1.set_vexpand(True)
    self.box_textview.pack_start(scrolledwindow1, True, True, 0)

    self.textview = Gtk.TextView()
    self.textview.set_wrap_mode(Gtk.WrapMode.WORD)
    self.textbuffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
    self.textbuffer.set_text("text")
    scrolledwindow1.add(self.textview)
```

Comment: Look into GtkPaned.

Comment: I saw GtkPaned, but I don't want the size of the sidebar to be expandable by the user - just like in a file manager. Anyway, For now I'm gonna ty it...

Comment: Have you tried setting a `width_request` on the sidebar Box?

Comment: Yes, but to no avail. But it seems like GtkPaned turned out to fit my needs. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try:

```
self.box_editview = Gtk.Box( orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=0, width_request=200 )
self.box.pack_start( self.box_editview, False, False, 0 )
```